# Getting 'data-wssurvey' when using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is that bootstrap's own thing that he/she/it uses to do something? Or is that an abnormal behavior? I see that in my <kbd>Inspect Element</kbd> **feature** of *Google Chrome* whereas I didn't wrote it in my markup. See this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Many Bootstrap components leverage data- attributes, however, I'm not aware that data-wssurvey is a part of default Bootstrap. If you didn't add this to the markup, it's likely that some Javascript you have included in the page is adding data-wssurvey to the body tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that little tag is being added by the "Webpage Screenshot" extension.

On my computer, I went to chrome://extensions/ then disabled "Webpage Screenshot Capture" and the data-wssurvey attribute disappeared.

Also, there was a javascript error message appearing in the console for every page I loaded, and that went away after disabling the webpage screenshot capture extension.

Comment: Adam, can you please add a link to the specific extension you mentioned and which operating system you were using it on? I am unable to reproduce the issue here.